# COUNTIF ignoring duplicates across multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to find how to use the COUNTIFS function in excel to count instances of "C.B. Type 16" across multiple columns while ignoring duplicates. Determining whether or not they are duplicates are determined by two seperate columns. It's a bit tricky. Here is a sample of the data:

[image: Sample Data]

ChatGPT has not been any help, so I have come to the humans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If I am not mistaken, then the following formula should work, as it assumes per the tag posted in the OP, there is no `Excel Constraints` that said:*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I7</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _data, B7:G20,
     SUM(--(CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(_data),3)),2)=I6)))
```

---

- Using `LET()` function to read the functions and variables applied more clearly and enhances the readability as well reduces the repetitions of functions or ranges.
- `_data` variable refers to the range.
- Using `TOCOL()` function to convert the array into a single range.
- Using `WRAPROWS()` function to convert the array into `#` of rows * `3` columns.
- Extracting unique items by using `UNIQUE()` function.
- Using `CHOOSECOLS()` function so it can be compared with the cell reference `I6` which reads `C.B. Type 16` (which is in question for the counts).
- Since it returns an array of `TRUE` & `FALSE` converting it to `1` and `0` using double unary `--`.
- Lastly, wrapping within `SUM()` to get the total unique counts.

---